# Want all the value from Table2 against each entry in Table1

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 tables i.e Table1 and Table2.

Now in table1 there are some duplicate entries who performed some action at different time. Table2 has 1 or duplicate entries who again performed some action at different time.

When I perform Vlookup on values of Table1 from Table2 it just picks the 1st value and applies it to all the duplicate values.

Explanation for how I want the result to be:
There are 3 entries against 'c' in Table1 and 2 entries against 'c' in Table2. I want that both the entries of 'c' in Table2 to appear against 3 entries of 'c' in Table1 (3rd entry will be the duplicate of 2nd entry). Final output is pasted below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This bit doesn't make sense to me, can you update it? *I want that both the entries of 'c' in Table2 to appear against 3 entries of 'c' in Table1 (3rd entry will be the duplicate of 2nd entry).*

Comment: I basically want the result as shown in Final table. Wondering what formula can be used

Comment: What you said you want,and what the final table shows are slightly different. Therefore asking for a clarification...

Comment: Hmmm. I think it's difficult to explain in writing. But yes basically I want the result to be as shown in the final table. I could have used Vlookup but it just picks the first value where as I want all the values to be pulled up from table 2 and then the result should be as shown in Final Table

Comment: So why does the 1st C row from Table 2 go against the 1st C row from Table 1, but the 2nd  C row from Table 2 goes against the 2nd and 3rd rows of Table 1 ? Why not the 1st C row from Table 2 going against going against the 1st and 2nd row of Table 1 and the 2nd C row from Table 2 going against the 3rd C row from Table 1 ? The output in Final Table seems arbitrary - how would someone suggest a programmatic solution without the logic being explicit ?

Comment: So the logic is that there are 3 'c' in table 1 and 2 'c' in table 2. Hence the value of  2nd 'c' (basically last value) gets applied to 3rd 'c' in table 1. Had there been 3 'c' in table 2 then it would have been applied against 3rd 'c' in table 1.

Or another logic can be that

3rd 'c' in table 1 is left blank or NA, since there are only 2 'c' in table 2. 
My motive is to fill the values against entries of table 1. If there were just 1 'c' in table 1 and more than 1 in table '2' then value of 1st 'c' from table 2 is matched against value of 'c' in table 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

[image: Retrieve all values corresponding to desired lookup value]

Based upon this screenshot, function that does the trick is 'filter', *vide-licit*:

```
=FILTER($C$3:$C$9,$B$3:$B$9=E2)
```

Notes: customise function by changing ranges $C$3:$C$9 (column of data to retrieve) and $B$3:$B$9 (column to filter/apply "lookup") to fulfil your specific requirements...

References/notes for further detail:
[Filter function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60662&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)